# Jech Set Theory: Proof that the separative quotient of a generic set is generic

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, forcing

Jech's Set Theory, 3rd edition, has the following result:

> Lemma 14.13: (i) In the ground model M, let Q be the separative quotient of P and let h map P onto Q such that (14.5) holds. If $G \subset P$ is generic over M then $h(G) \subset Q$ is generic over M

The (14.5) condition referenced is i: $x \leq y$ implies $h(x) \leq h(y)$ and ii: $x$ and $y$ are compatible in $P$ if and only if $h(x)$ and $h(y)$ are compatible in $Q$.

In particular, since every generic set over a model $M$ is a filter, this implies that $h(G)$ must be a filter as well, and hence that it's closed above in the partial ordering on $Q$. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to prove this.

In other words: given $p \in h(G), p \leq q$, how can we verify that $q \in h(G)$? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: By definition of separative quotient, and the associated map, this should be fairly straight forward. Try proving that a quotient of a linearly pre-ordered set is a linear order. That is similar.

Comment: What about {a,b,c,d} with the partial order b<a, b<c, d<c? I know this can't actually be a counterexample but I'm not sure why: can't we take the filter whose only element is a, and wouldn't its image under the quotient no longer be a filter?

Comment: If all elements are compatible, the quotient is a single point.

Comment: If I wrote that the way I meant to, then b and d should not be compatible.

Comment: Ohh, sorry. You're right. But then a generic filter is either $\{a,b,c\}$ or $\{c,d\}$.

Comment: Ohh ok, I think this may be my issue. I had been assuming that without knowing what the ground model is, we yet don't know which filters are generic -- that's wrong?

Comment: Well, no, that's not really the point. I mean, if you look at your finite example again, then the order is already separative. So I'm not sure what your example would suppose to be?

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to make this the last comment. I don't believe the order is separative because I don't think it separates a and b -- so the quotient would collapse a and b but leave c and d intact. If we consider the filter consisting only of a (that's a filter, right?) then its image under the quotient would be one point, not closed above.

Comment: Okay, I'm clearly too tired to think about this order properly... :)

Comment: No worries lol, thanks for giving it a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this we will prove something stronger:
If $[p] \in h(G) \wedge [p] \le [q] \rightarrow q \in G$ this is stronger than the main statement because this actually implies that every representative of $[q]$ lies in $G$. Now it follows from the definition that $[p] \le [q]$ implies that for all $r$, $r$ is compatible with $p \rightarrow r$ is compatible with $q$. Now consider the set $D = \{r \in P: r$ is incompatible with $p$ or $r \le q\}$. You can easily check that $D$ is dense in $P$ and so $G \cap D \neq \emptyset$. Then there exists $r$ such that $r\in G$ and notice that $r$ can't be incompatible with $p$ so $r \le q$ and lastly we have $q \in G$ as needed.

Comment: Thanks! That clears it up nicely